# Rewriting rules: difference between 'init', 'rewrite_rules_array', 'generate_rewrite_rules'?

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I was wondering, what's the difference, and best filter/action to add rewrite rules? I used all but I still can't say why should I use one or the other.

```
add_action('init', 'add_rewrite_rules'); // or:
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_rewrite_rules'); // or:
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array','add_rewrite_rules');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use whatever is simplest for your needs.

If you just need to add a rule to the stack, use `add_rewrite_rule` on `init`.

`generate_rewrite_rules` and `rewrite_rules_array` give you access to the whole rewrite rules array. Use these if you need to modify, remove, or reorder the rules.